# Drawing specific RGB on touch screen

Tags: arduino-mega, display, tft

I have the Arduino MEGA and an adafruit touch screen 2.8 inches.

**My goal is to draw a pixel given a specific RGB**

I am using the `ILI9341`, `GFX`, and `TFT.h` libraries to draw and control the touch screen. I noticed the `drawPixel` function given, in which it takes in three parameters and draws the pixel:

```
tft.drawPixel(4,4,ILI9341_BLUE);
```

But, I am trying to draw a pixel with specific a RGB. So instead, the function would ideally need 5 parameters instead of 3, x, y, and then R, G, and B:

```
tft.idealDrawPixel(5,6,89,234,76);
```

I tried putting in a number as the third parameter and not `ILI9341_COLOR`, and the screen just prints blue:

```
tft.drawPixel(45,67,255);
```

Is there a function that allows me to draw RGB pixels specifically? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the second paragraph on [Adafruit's Graphics Library webpage](https://learn.adafruit.com/2-8-tft-touchscreen/graphics-library),

> First thing to note is that color is 16-bit, and that includes Red, Green and Blue in a 16-bit variable. The way the color is packed in is the top 5 bits are red, the middle 6 bits are green and the bottom 5 bits are blue.

If you want to specify 8-bit color components, you could write an intermediary routine to translate from that form to the 565 form.  For example:

```
#define rgbDrawPixel(x,y,r,g,b) drawPixel(x,y,(((r)&0b11111000)<<8)|(((g)&0b11111100)<<3)|(((b)&0b11111000)>>3))
```

Note, this assumes the TFT library you're using has the same specs as Adafruit's.  That might or might not be; I don't know how to account for a 255 color number showing up as blue rather than white.